# Which Linux distributions enable AT_RANDOM canary initialisation by default?

Tags: linux, security, kernel

Which Linux distributions enable `AT_RANDOM` canary initialisation by default, and since which version?

You can test if you have `AT_RANDOM` canary initialisation enabled by running:

```
LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 /bin/true | grep AT_RANDOM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses a random canary by [default](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/features/security).  I believe all of the packages in apt are compiled with this canary,  there maybe a few exceptions such as 3rd party repositories.  I don't know if this specific `AT_RANDOM` canary is being used by anyone.